# Mysql LEFT JOIN gives me result, RIGHT JOIN NOT also INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql

i trie to get results from two tables in my sql query. But all what i got, is the smaller table.
So the LEFT JOIN gives me the results from the smaller table, which holds only 5 columns.
The bigger one has about 25 columns. So if i trie to set the RIGHT JOIN, no results are shown. But also i got no error from mysql, just an empty result. Also the INNER JOIN dosen't work. Heres my query:

```
SELECT zu.*, peps.*
  FROM audit.zusammen zu
  RIGHT JOIN  audit.pep peps
    ON zu._id_fk = peps.id
  WHERE MATCH (zu.concat_Names) AGAINST ('merkel' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  ORDER BY zu.last_Name
```

Comment: update  your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Which table is the big table: `peps`?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean *row* when you say *column*.

Also assuming that the *big table* is `peps`, I think that you want:

```
SELECT zu.*, peps.* 
FROM audit.pep peps 
LEFT JOIN audit.zusammen zu 
    ON zu.id_fk = peps.id  
    AND MATCH (zu.concat_Names) AGAINST ('merkel' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY zu.last_Name
```

This will produce as many record as there are in `peps`, with optional data coming from `zusammen` for records that match on `id_fk` and whose `concat_Names` satifsfy the full text seach on `'merkel'`.

Recommended reading: [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join)